# Hide left arrow on default slide

Tags: jquery

I need little help with my script. i'm trying to hide left navigation arrow from default slide(#slide1). Works at first, but as user slide through slideshow and comes back to same slide(#slide1)  arrow is shown.
Looking at  my script, can someone  tell me what I'm doing wrong:

```
var curSlide = 0;

 function setSlide(num,dir){  
   var oldSlide = curSlide;  
    if(num>5) num = 1;  
  else if(num<1) num = 5;  
  var showDir = "";
  var hideDir = "";  
     (dir=="f"){
     showDir = "right";  
     hideDir = "left";  
  } else {  
    showDir = "left";  
    hideDir = "right";  
}  
if(curSlide == 0){  
$("#slide1").show();  
$('#left_arrow').hide();  
curSlide = 1;      

} else {  
curSlide = num;      

$("#slide"+curSlide).show('slide',{direction:showDir},600);  
    $("#slide"+oldSlide).hide('slide',{direction:hideDir},600);  
$('#left_arrow').show();  
}
```

}

```
 function nextSlide(){  
   setSlide(curSlide*1+1,"f");  
   }     

function prevSlide(){  
setSlide(curSlide*1-1,"b");  
 }  



$(document).ready(function () { 
if($('#show_picks')) {  

$('#show_picks area').each(function() {  
        $(this).click(function(e) {  
            e.preventDefault();  
            setSlide($(this).attr('id'),"f");  
        });  
        $(this).mouseover(function(e) {  
            $(this).css("cursor", "pointer");  
        });  
        $(this).mouseout(function(e) {  
            $(this).css("cursor", "default");  
        });  

    });  
}   
    $("#left_arrow").click(function(e) {  
            e.preventDefault();  
            prevSlide();  
    });

    $("#right_arrow").click(function(e) {  
            e.preventDefault();  
            nextSlide();  
    });


    $("#left_arrow").mouseover(function(e) {  
            $("#left_arrow").css("cursor", "pointer");  
    }); 


    $("#left_arrow").mouseout(function(e) {  
            $("#left_arrow").css("cursor", "default");  
    });


    $("#right_arrow").mouseover(function(e) {  
            $("#right_arrow").css("cursor", "pointer");  
    });


    $("#right_arrow").mouseout(function(e) {  
            $("#right_arrow").css("cursor", "default");  
    });  

     for(var i=2;i<6;i++){  
        $("#slide"+i).hide();   
      }  
    setSlide(0,"f");  
});
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem is you check if the current slide is 0 hide left arrow. this only happen the fist time scripts load.

in execution never is 0 again because of

```
if(num>5) num = 1;  
  else if(num<1) num = 5;
```

and

```
curSlide = 1;
```

and

```
curSlide = num;
```

you set num between 1 and 5 or 1 never 0 and your condition to hide is

```
if(curSlide == 0){  
$("#slide1").show();  
$('#left_arrow').hide();
```

you must set `curslide=1` at the begging and change the condition to  `if(curSlide == 1){`

Comment: it dont work because of `if(curSlide == 0){  
$("#slide1").show();  
$('#left_arrow').hide();  
curSlide = 1;      

} else {  
curSlide = num;      

$("#slide"+curSlide).show('slide',{direction:showDir},600);  
    $("#slide"+oldSlide).hide('slide',{direction:hideDir},600);  
$('#left_arrow').show();  
}` you have to rethink the if and put out the else the .show() and .hide()

Comment: function Controls(curSlide){
   
 if(curSlide==1){ $('#left_arrow').hide() } else{ $('#left_arrow').show() }
 
  }

Comment: This was fixed, but it was nothing to do with IF statement.